# Is there a way to have guard livereload open the page being edited?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard

Lets say I'm on the homepage. I edit the view file to the homepage and the browser reloads the index page. Yay!!!

Now, inside of my text editor, I decide that I am going to edit the about page. *Without going to the browser*, is there a method of having the guard livereload not only reload the page, but take me to the about page?